# How to disable/change homepage in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I manage to disable the homepage on Prestashop.
I want that users arrive in a specific category and not on the homepage.

I've tried to do it in the htaccess file with a redirection of `index.php` to `index.php?category_id=1`.
It works but it generate the error `Technical error unable to load form` when the user try to create an account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This applies to PrestaShop 1.5

You may edit *controllers/front/IndexController.php* file, which is responsible for the homepage, adding Tools::redirect call to whatever controller you want (this example is to cart).

```
public function initContent()
{
    parent::initContent();

    Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=cart'.($_REQUEST ? '&'.http_build_query($_REQUEST, '', '&') : ''), __PS_BASE_URI__, null, 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');

    $this->context->smarty->assign('HOOK_HOME', Hook::exec('displayHome'));
    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'index.tpl');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for one way you can simply add a redirect to your index.php file, but that I guess is already evaluated and rejected solution:

```
header('index.php?category_id=1');
exit;
```

Another way of doing this might be using the prestashops modules, for example there is a module "homefeatured" which displays exactly the products for the home category and you can hook it on home position through Modules -> Positions.

If you would mind telling me the exact major version of prestashop you are using maybe I could tell something more.